# Como converter latitude/longitude para Double em C#

Tags: c#, .net, conversão-de-tipo, culture

Estou com um problema, pois tenha uma variável do tipo `string` e preciso converter para o tipo `double` sem perder o "ponto". Exemplo: `string latitude = "-8.709006"` ao converter seja igual a: `-8.709006` Mas até então já fiz vários teste diferentes e nada.

```
string latitude = "-8.709006";
double lat = Double.Parse(latitude);
//Mas ele esta me trazendo: -8709006 e nao -8.709006
```

Já fiz de outra forma também mas não obtiver resultado:

```
string latitude = "-8.709006";
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cult = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
double lat = double.Parse(latitude, cult);
//Desta vez o resultado foi: -8,709006 e nao -8.709006
```

Como também tentei assim:

```
string latitude = "-8.709006";
    double lat = Double.Parse(latitude, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    //E o resultado foi: -8,709006 e nao -8.709006
```

Comment: Também já tentei usando o CultureInfo para "pt-BR" e nada: System.Globalization.CultureInfo cult = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");

Comment: Pra mim deu certo https://dotnetfiddle.net/NMFJe4 acho que o seu problema não está na conversão e sim na apresentação.

Comment: Concordo com o @bigown, o problema parece estar na apresentação e não na conversão em si.

Comment: @bigown aceibei de da um Ctrl+C no teu código e o resultado continua sendo o mesmo aqui para min: -8,709006 realmente não mais o que está acontecendo!

Comment: @JoaquimCaetanoTeixeira Já verificou as configurações de fuso horário e idioma no Painel de Controle?

Comment: @JoaquimCaetanoTeixeira O tipo `double` armazenado na memória, nada tem a ver com a representação em forma de string usando `,` ou `.`. Quando você vai verificar o valor após fazer a conversão, o que é mostrado para você é a representação em forma de string, usando a configuração de linguagem do seu sistema operacional.

Comment: @JoaquimCaetanoTeixeira Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

A conversão parece que está funcionando ok. Se você que mostrar em um formato específico você precisa especificar este formato:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine(double.Parse("-8.709006", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US", true)));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/PIE2vI). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NmULpe). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Culture/DoubleUs.cs).

Comment: nesse caso realmente está funcionando, mas é o seguinte para eu chegar nesse resultado da última linha ele já está convertido novamente para o tipo "string"

Comment: Tem várias formas de fazer isto uma delas é assim, você pega a *string* formatada do jeito que você deseja.

Comment: é que preciso dele formatado mas do tipo double.

Comment: `lat` é do tipo double. Um tipo numérico não tem formatação. Ele é um número. Só *strings*s possuem formatação. Quando você quer fazer cálculos você faz com o número, não importa a formatação. Quando você quer apresentar o número aí você apresenta como *string*. Só é possível apresentar como *string*. Mesmo que você não esteja vendo, uma conversão sempre é feita para apresentar. Não existe outra forma de fazer isto em qualquer linguagem. O que muda de uma linguagem para outra é apenas o detalhe.

Comment: Mas é que nesse meu caso eu não faço nenhum cálculo com ele, eu estou utilizando para latitude e longitude com a 'API GMap .NET' e se eu o passar sem o ponto ele vai para um local totalmente diferente e o método do GMap .NET receber como parâmetro o tipo double.

Comment: Aí você está falando de uma API específica. Não sei como ela passa os dados. Mas ou ela passa como tipo `double` e não importa o formato, até porque o tipo não tem formato ou passa por *string* e aí eu te passei o jeito de formatar como você quer. Fora isto, você precisa fazer uma pergunta com seu problema real. O que você perguntou, eu respondi.

Answer (score -2):

ok! Crie a variavel
var provider = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

E depois converta a string lat_Variable para double:

double Lat = Double.Parse(lat_Variable, provider);

Espero que funcione!